# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am writing a program that calculates the minimum and maximum of 10 numbers from a list (data1). I am receiving a "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" for the following lines:

```
temp_min10=min(data1[x-z][3])
temp_max10=max(data1[x-z][2])
```

Full program:

```
x=int(0)
for line in data1:
    if x>=9:
        min10=0
        max10=0
        for z in range(0,10):
            temp_min10 = temp_max10 = 0
            temp_min10=min(data1[x-z][3])
            if temp_min10<min10:
                min10=temp_min10
            temp_max10=max(data1[x-z][2])
            if temp_max10>max10:
                max10=temp_max10
            d_chan.append([max10,min10])
    else:
        d_chan.append([0,0])
        x+=1
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show us a `data1`. Also, what's with the `int(0)`?

Comment: Yeah definitely a series of stupid mistakes... data1 is a list of lists containing numbers. I originally tried int(0) because I couldn't figure out the float problem (now have "x=0"). The code was supposed to iterate through a certain amount of numbers to determine the max and min. I solved the problem using a simple function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible args for `min` and `max` are either *one* iterable or 2 or more scalars. Docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max). You have given it one arg which is not an iterable; it's a float.

Aside: (1) Your indentation as displayed is patently incorrect. You need to (a) avoid tabs in your source file (b) ensure that your indentation is logically correct. (2) Your code is iterating `for line in data1:` but never mentions `line` again; looks like you need to check carefully what you are doing with `x`; it's not obvious.

**Update** after reading your code again:

The following code will probably do what you want.

```
# These assertions state the presumed effect of code that you have not included.
assert len(data1) == 10
assert d_chan == []
# I suspect a typo in the OP ... it makes more sense for the 
# two values below to be the same.
MIN_COL = 3
MAX_COL = 2
d_chan = [[0, 0] for i in xrange(9)]
min10 = min(data1[i][MIN_COL] for i in xrange(10))      
max10 = max(data1[i][MAX_COL] for i in xrange(10))
d_chan.append([max10, min10])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - very stupid error. I used `x` and `for line in data1:` as a complicated way to get `for x in len(data1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
min_number = reduce(min,data1)
max_number = reduce(max,data1)
```